# Sublime Autocomplete that calls plugin

Tags: autocomplete, ide, sublimetext3

I've create an autocomplete file that looks like that:

```
{
    "scope": "",

    "completions":
    [
            { "trigger": "ticket", "contents": "# ticket No.\"$1\" Status: $0" }

    ]
```

}

I'm working on a plugin that receives ticket number and returns status. Is it possible to enter the variable $1 when autocompleted and make the $0 variable filled by plugin function?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you'd like to trigger the completion, type (for example) `12345` in spot `$1`, then have the `Status` value for ticket 12345 looked up and completed by the plugin? If that's the case, then yes, that's quite possible.

Comment: [`sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions()`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener.on_query_completions) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, That's what I mean, and I will try it and write back. thank you.